# Subtracting two dataframe columns with timestamps

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I have the following code to calculate the difference in hours from two dataframe columns and put that in a new column:

```
def transform_data(data_frame):

    start = pd.to_datetime(data_frame['start'])
    end = pd.to_datetime(data_frame['end'])

    print(start, end)

    data_frame['hours'] = (end-start)

    return fetch_layers(data_frame)
```

If I run this it prints the following:

```
3402959   2010-09-06 09:00:00
3402961   2010-09-07 09:30:00
...
3403125   2011-04-15 08:30:00
3403126   2011-04-18 09:00:00
Name: start, dtype: datetime64[ns] 
3402959   2010-09-06 18:00:00
3402961   2010-09-07 18:00:00
...
Name: end, dtype: datetime64[ns]
Series([], Name: start, dtype: datetime64[ns]) Series([], Name: end, dtype:    datetime64[ns])
```

From this it seems that both columns now have datetimes, but when subtracting it gives the following error:

```
 TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]')    and dtype('O')
```

The weird thing is that this code works on most of my data, but only fails in a small part of the data. What causes this error?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your dataframe where it fails?

Comment: Well, the data that I printed is where it fails. The whole file is to big to print here I think

Comment: Can you provide the version of pandas you're using?  You should be able to get it through `pd.show_versions()`.

Comment: The version I'm using is 0.17.1